# Return by reference from template

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, return-value

What is the difference between returning `*this` and `this` from a template function which returns object by reference? 
Both options compiles without any problems in VS2013;

The code is something like

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass
{

public:
    MyClass(){ }
    ~MyClass();

    MyClass& operator=(const MyClass&);

};

template <typename T>
MyClass<T>& MyClass<T>::operator=(const MyClass& s_from)
{

    //do some work
    return *this;
    //also works
    //return this
}

template <typename T>
MyClass<T>::~MyClass()
{

}
```

Comment: `retun this;` should not compile. Make a [mcve] if it does.

Comment: It does compile. Thats why im asking.

Comment: when you instantiate your template and use operator=, you get error. see my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For template compiler checks only syntax. When you instantiate your template and try to copy objects, you get compile error for return this:

```
 MyQueue<int> a;
 MyQueue<int> b;
 a = b; /// ops
```

Or you can explicit instantiate your template (in that case compiler generates all member and you see all errors)

```
template class MyQueue<int>;
```

So return *this is only way to return reference for object from member function or operator.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is of type `MyQueue<T>* const` while `*this` is `MyQueue<T>`, so `return this` should not work unless there is a implicit cast from `MyQueue<T>*` to `MyQueue<T>`.